# How to find the last position in numpy.zeros

Tags: python, numpy

Very new to programming, sorry, I don't know if my question even has any sens..

Here's my code :

```
import numpy 
import pylab 
import random 
L=[]
n =int(input("number of steps :"))
  
x = numpy.zeros(n) 
y = numpy.zeros(n) 
 
for i in range(1, n): 
    Direction = random.randint(1, 4) 
    if Direction == 1: 
        x[i] = x[i - 1] + 1
        y[i] = y[i - 1] 
    elif Direction == 2: 
        x[i] = x[i - 1] - 1
        y[i] = y[i - 1] 
    elif Direction == 3: 
        x[i] = x[i - 1] 
        y[i] = y[i - 1] + 1
    else: 
        x[i] = x[i - 1] 
        y[i] = y[i - 1] - 1
    L.append(Direction)
print("last direction was :",x ,y)
      

pylab.title("Walking)") 
pylab.plot(x, y) 
pylab.savefig("walk.png") 
pylab.show()
```

It's basically a pixel moving in 2D dimension on x and y axis N times and i'm trying to find the last position it's at. I did that by doing print (x,y) and noting the last number it gave me, but trying to find a better solution .. any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: The last value of a numpy array can be indexed just like lists etc. in Python with a `-1`.  So the final position  could be retrieve with `x[-1]`  and `y[-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way to think about this. Instead of looping and adding, just keep track of the direction vectors. In your example, you have four possible ways to travel:

```
directions = np.array([[1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]])
```

perhaps representing East, West, North, South.

You can generate a random list of these vectors in many ways, one easy-to-understand way is to make a random list of indexes, and use those to pick which direction to go. For example:

```
indices = np.random.randint(4, size=n)
# just a list of ints like array([2, 3, 1, 1, 3])

direction_vectors = directions[indices]
# a list of vectors
```

With the above indexes this would give you a list of vectors like:

```
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 0, -1],
       [-1,  0],
       [-1,  0],
       [ 0, -1]])
```

The nice thing about vectors is that you can add them to get the final position. With numpy, that's as simple as calling `sum()`:

```
direction_vectors.sum(axis=0)
# array([-2, -1])
```

Which gives you the final position: `array([-2, -1])`. In total you have traveled `-2` in the `x` direction and `-1` in the `y` direction.

In all that might look like:

```
n = 5
directions = np.array([[1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]])

direction_vectors = directions[np.random.randint(len(directions), size=n)]
direction_vectors.sum(axis=0)
```

If you want to start somewhere other than the origin, you can just add that point.

If you want the current point at each step given your direction vectors, you can take the cumulative sum with [`cumsum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html):

```
> direction_vectors.cumsum(axis=0)
array([[ 0,  1],
   [ 0,  0],
   [-1,  0],
   [-2,  0],
   [-2, -1]])
```

Finding the last cummulative sum, is the same as finding the sum above, so you can index the final position:

```
positions = direction_vectors.cumsum(axis=0)
positions[-1]
# array([-2, -1])
```

Comment: Thank you !! This is what I needed